# Corda with token and accounts

Tags: corda

We are working with token and accounts at Corda with Kotlin. I will detail the scenario to clarify.
We have a node1 and a node2.
We created a "OurTokenType" that extends from TokenType.
We created two accounts (seller and buyer) on node1 and shared them with node2.
By the business rule of the application, node2 is the one who issues the tokens (FungibleToken), and the issue worked correctly. In the end, node1 and node2 have access to the FungibleStates for the issue transaction.
Our problem is in the transfer of these tokens. When we try to transfer the tokens from the account seller to the buyer.
In our scenario, the transfer of tokens can happen on node1 or node2.
When we transfer through node1, which is the host of the accounts, we can use the MoveFungibleTokensFlow class that works and the FungibleStates on node1 are updated to the correct value. However, when we added node2 as an observer in the observerSessions parameter, the FungibleStates on node2 were not updated correctly.
And when we do the transfer by node2, which is NOT the host of the accounts, using the MoveFungibleTokensFlow class, it doesn't work, it generates an exception of com.r3.corda.lib.tokens.selection.InsufficientBalanceException: Insufficient spendable states identified, even with balance .

My question is, can I use the MoveFungibleTokensFlow class to transfer between accounts even if they are on another host?
And when we run on the node that hosts the accounts, what is the problem to update the FungibleStates when using observerSessions?
Or if I must follow the example of the link https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/tree/master/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `MoveFungibleTokensFlow` doesn't have an input parameter that specifies who's the source of the moved tokens, and that's because it considers the initiator of the flow as the source of the tokens.

```kotlin
class MoveFungibleTokensFlow
@JvmOverloads
constructor(
        val partiesAndAmounts: List<PartyAndAmount<TokenType>>,
        override val participantSessions: List<FlowSession>,
        override val observerSessions: List<FlowSession> = emptyList(),
        val queryCriteria: QueryCriteria? = null,
        val changeHolder: AbstractParty? = null
) : AbstractMoveTokensFlow() {
```

- You are not correct about "both node1 and node2 see the issued tokens", in `FungibleToken` the only participant is the `holder` of the tokens, so when tokens are issued to seller and buyer accounts, the only participant is the node that hosts those accounts (i.e. node1).
- Going back to my first point, because only node1 has the issued tokens, and you're running the move flow on node2 (the flow consider node2 as the source of the tokens, but node2 doesn't have them); that's why you're getting the insufficient balance error.
- Even if you added node2 as an observer when you issued the tokens to buyer and seller (i.e. both node1 and node2 have the resulting tokens); if you dig deep through the code of `MoveFungibleTokensflow` which inherits from `AbstractMoveTokensFlow` which relies on `ObserverAwareFinalityFlow` to sign the transaction, you'll see inside `ObserverAwareFinalityFlow` that it doesn't call `CollectSignatures` flow, it only signs the transaction locally (see [here](https://github.com/corda/token-sdk/blob/bf10299e01deeb627d5f438e8059054f3aaa4b77/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/tokens/workflows/internal/flows/finality/ObserverAwareFinalityFlow.kt#L69-L73)); meaning only the node that holds the private keys of the accounts can sign on the move command, and since node1 is the `host` of buyer and seller; then node1 is the owner of the private/public keys and only node1 can sign on behalf of buyer and seller. So even if you shared buyer and seller accounts with node2; only node1 can sign, and since you're calling `MoveFungibleTokensFlow` from node2 (your 2nd scenario), it will fail when it reaches the part where it needs to sign on behalf of seller (to move its tokens), because node2 doesn't own the private key of that account.
- On a side note, when you call `MoveFungibleTokesnFlow` from node1 to move the tokens of seller to buyer; make sure that you supply a value for `queryCriteria` to select only the tokens that belong to seller; if you don't supply a value; then the flow will pick any tokens that are hosted on node1 so you might end up moving tokens that belong to other accounts.
- Also make sure to supply a value for `changeHolder`, so that the change goes back to seller, if you keep it empty; any resulting change will be assigned to the initiating node (i.e node1) instead of the account.
- You can find lots of helpful tips in [my article](https://blog.b9lab.com/cordacon-2019-highlights-r3s-tokens-sdk-6bb12a5743bd) on Tokens SDK.
- Also, R3 recently released a free Corda course; it has a [great section](https://training.corda.net/libraries/tokens-sdk/) on Tokens SDK.
- In order for you to be able to move tokens from seller to buyer using node1 or node2 you have to rely on the utility function `addMoveTokens()` instead of the ready flows (i.e. `MoveFungibleTokensFlow`) (because of the above mentioned reasons). So you have to create the transaction yourself, then add the tokens to be moved using `addMoveTokens()`, then you have to collect the signatures (of the seller) using `CollectSignatures` flow (the seller will sign in the responder flow); also you have to take care of finalizing the transaction.
- Just to clarify the above flow, your flow should check if it's the host of the seller; then it can sign locally, if it's not the host; then you have to create a `FlowSession` with the host of the account so you can collect its signature (i.e. its approval to move the token that it holds).
- Samples repo has [some examples](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Tokens) that use `addMoveTokens()`; I recommend spending some time to explore them.

Comment: We managed to solve it.
We made two flows, one called when the executing node is the host of the accounts and another when the executing node is different from the host of the accounts.
In the first case, we use the auxiliary flow addMoveFungibleTokens and share the FungibleToken (transaction.tx.outRefsOfType <FungibleToken> ()) with the nodes through ShareStateAndSyncAccounts. Continue...

Comment: In the second case, we retrieve the current holder session of the tokens, and through the response flow we retrieve the tokens with DatabaseTokenSelection :: generateMove. In the main stream we use addMoveTokens. We share tokens with nodes in the same way as in the first case.
Thank you very much for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Let me break down your question into two parts:

1. Observer session doesn't update automatically: 
   Here is an example of how we would trigger the update on the observer session: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Tokens/stockpaydividend/workflows/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/samples/stockpaydividend/flows/AnnounceDividend.kt#L37
   This will ensure the observer's token state is updated whenever the maintainer makes an update. (Note: only the maintainer should make the update, not the owner)
2. Fungible token transfer between two parties: Yes. it is doable. This line of code is the beginning of FungibleToken transfer in the worldcupticketbooking sample: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Accounts/worldcupticketbooking/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/t20worldcup/flows/DVPAccountsHostedOnDifferentNodes.kt#L102 It definitely works.

I see you mentioned that you had an error message on `InsufficientBalanceException`, if I were you, I would start digging in from there, and see which token is being queried exactly.